# Encryption values not correct in HCL Notes emails

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm currently looking at tens of thousands of emails in an unencrypted .nsf HCL notes file and I am using a third-party tool to access these emails. The third-party tool is checking for 'Document.isEncrypted()' to identify encrypted documents but it isn't decrypting them and therefore, I feel there is an issue with some of the emails actually being encrypted but not being marked as encrypted. Checking the properties of some of the emails, I see the below:-

- Some have the 'encrypt' value as '1' and some just as ''
- Some have the 'encrypt' value as '1' but have no '$seal' value

I therefore created an agent with the `'@Command( [ToolsRefreshSelectedDocs] )'` with the hope of resetting properties on the files. This seems to work fine when I tested it on a handful of emails and they are are accessible by the third party tool but when I try and run this across the entire content of the .nsf (around 45GB), it stops running after a few thousand and the progress bar just disappears.

Any suggestions on alternatives to the Refresh of Documents to achieve the same outcome as the above? In theory, I'm looking to remove encryption from all documents. I did also try this but it doesn't work:-

https://web.archive.org/web/20200923074841/https:/searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Remove-Encryption-from-Mail

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the solution of the wrong problem.

You are absolutely right, that there are mails that can not be identified by simply looking at the items. e.g. there are really documents that are encrypted but do not have the "Encrypt" item set to "1".

BUT: The LotusScript function "IsEncrypted" usually works fine with these documents as it uses a C-API call that identifies these documents even if the items are "off".

You problem is of another kind: Sometimes there are documents in a database that are properly encrypted but still cannot be decrypted.

Most often these are mails that are encrypted for "somebody else" and not the current ID you use.
Only one of the IDs with a secret key matching the keys that the document was encrypted with can decrypt the message.

Sometimes Users loose their IDs or people go and come back. Then a new ID is calculated with the same name and mails that had been encrypted with the old ID will not be readably anymore.

So you need to enhance your LotusScript to throw an error with the universal id of these documents and then check manually if you can find another way to decrypt them (probably with the ID of the sender of the mail).

If you can't find a proper ID then this eMail is lost forever...

Comment: Thanks Tode. I did verify that the ID file I had allowed me to access the content in Notes but the third party tool still couldn't handle it. Ultimately I wrote a Lotus Script that refreshed each document individually and that worked fine